# Ergodic actions of orthogonal group $O(2)$

Tags: examples-counterexamples, group-actions, ergodic-theory

I am looking for  explicit ergodic action of $O(2)$ on a von Neumann algebra $M$. ($O(2)$=orthogonal group of $2\times 2$ matrix)